# Evaluate $∫_C(4y^3+\cos x^2 )\,dx-(4x^3+\sin y^2)\,dy$ where $C$ is the boundary of the disk centered at the origin of radius $2$, oriented clockwise.

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to begin with this equations, doesn't really understand what does "$C$ is the boundary of the disk centered at the origin of radius $2$, oriented clockwise." mean.

Comment: Is the expression meant to contain $x^3,y^3,x^2$ and $y^2$ or $3x,3y,2x$ and $2y$? I can't tell by the way you have written it.

Comment: Is that $(\sin(x))^2$ or $\sin(x^2)$? Also have you tried looking at the problem in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Green's Theorem

$$\int_C (Pdx+Qdy)=-\int_S \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac
{\partial Q}{\partial x} \right)  $$

Here, $P=4y^3+\cos^2x$ and $Q=-(4x^3+\sin^2y)$.  Upon applying Green's Theorem, we find

$$\int_C (Pdx+Qdy) =-\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 12\rho^2\,\rho d\rho d\phi = -96\pi$$

---

Now, we evaluate directly the line integral.

To that end, we let $x=2\cos t$ and $y=2\sin t$, $0\le t\le 2\pi$.

Then, $dx=-2\sin t dt$ and $dy=2\cos t dt$.

The line integral becomes

$$\int_C (Pdx+Qdy)=-64\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\sin^4 t+\cos^4 t\right) dt-2\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin t \cos^2(2\cos t)+\cos t\sin^2(2\sin t))dt$$

We notice that the second integral is zero.  For the first integral, we use the identity $\sin^4 t+\cos^4 t=3/4$.  Thus, the line integral is $-64 \times 3/4 \times 2\pi=-96\pi$, which recovers the result from use of Green's Theorem!